# How to use "move2kube collect" command?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud-foundry

I am new to movetokube tool. I am struggling to understand how the move2kube collect command works. The [web site](https://move2kube.konveyor.io/) doesn't have any documentation on this command which is very surprising. I want to get all the applications installed in the Cloud Foundary cluster and I hope move2kube does this through move2kube collect command (or not?). I am not sure sure whether I have to execute the move2kube command on the Cloud Foundary cluster or K8 cluster. Please help!

I am executing the following move2kube command on a CF cluster

> move2kube collect

I see the following error

```
INFO[0000] Begin collection
INFO[0000] [*collector.ClusterCollector] Begin collection
WARN[0001] Error while fetching storage classes using command [/usr/local/bin/kubectl get sc -o yaml]
ERRO[0001] API request for server-group list failed
WARN[0001] Failed to retrieve preferred group information from cluster
WARN[0001] Failed to collect using the API. Error: "Get \"https://cluster02.someserver.com:8443/api?timeout=32s\": failed to refresh token: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401 \nResponse: {\"error\":\"unauthorized\",\"error_description\":\"Bad credentials\"}" . Falling back to using the CLI.
ERRO[0001] Error while running kubectl api-resources: exit status 1
WARN[0001] Failed to collect using the CLI. Error: "exit status 1"
WARN[0001] [*collector.ClusterCollector] failed. Error: "exit status 1"
INFO[0001] [*collector.ImagesCollector] Begin collection
INFO[0001] [*collector.ImagesCollector] Done
INFO[0001] [*collector.CFContainerTypesCollector] Begin collection
WARN[0002] Error while getting buildpacks : exit status 1
WARN[0002] Unable to collect buildpacks from cf instance : exit status 1
ERRO[0002] exit status 1
WARN[0002] Unable to find used buildpacks : exit status 1
INFO[0004] [*collector.CFContainerTypesCollector] Done
INFO[0004] [*collector.CfAppsCollector] Begin collection
ERRO[0004] exit status 1
WARN[0004] [*collector.CfAppsCollector] failed. Error: "exit status 1"
INFO[0004] Collection done
INFO[0004] Collect Output in [/home/mytest/move2kube/samples/m2k_collect]. Copy this directory into the source directory to be used for planning.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the move2kube GitHub page](https://github.com/konveyor/move2kube/blob/main/USAGE.md#usage):

> **Usage**
>
> **One step Simple approach**
>
> `move2kube transform -s src`
>
> **Two step involved approach**
>
> 1. *Plan* : Place source code in a directory say
>    `src` and generate a plan. For example, you can use the `samples`
>    directory. `move2kube plan -s src`
> 2. *Transform* : In the same directory,
>    invoke the below command. `move2kube transform`
>
> Note: If information about any runtime instance say cloud foundry or kubernetes cluster
> needs to be collected use `move2kube collect`. You can place the
> collected data in the `src` directory used in the plan.

And from [the article **Introducing Konveyor Move2Kube** on Medium](https://ashokponkumar.medium.com/introducing-konveyor-move2kube-f3b28e78cd22):

> **Move2Kube Usage**
>
> Move2Kube takes as input the source artifacts and
> outputs the target deployment artifacts.
>
> Move2Kube accomplishes the
> above activities using a 3 step approach of
>
> 1. *Collect* : If runtime
>    inspection is required, `move2kube collect` will analyse your runtime
>    environment such as cloud foundry or kubernetes, extract the required
>    metadata and output them as yaml files in `m2k_collect` folder.
>
> ...

Comment: The point you mentioned in the Note section about move2kube collect is very important because this is not very clear in any documentation I have seen in the internet.